# Plotly buttons can't return the correct scatter graph

Tags: python, button, plotly

I write a function for visualizing scatter plots of classification tasks.I want to update the scatter plot data and the x_axis and y_axis title by selecting the X-axis features and Y-axis features.Currently, when i change the features, the data update errors occur, and when i hover the scatter data, the text according it is also displayed wrong.Could anybody tell me how to modify my code? Thanks a lot! The code is as follows:

```
def drawScatterGraph(title, data, y_true, y_pred, y_name):
    data['True'] = y_true.reshape(-1, 1)
    data['Pred'] = y_pred.reshape(-1, 1)
    data['结果'] = y_true.reshape(-1, 1) == y_pred.reshape(-1, 1)
    data[['True', 'Pred']] = data[['True', 'Pred']].astype("object")
    data['结果'] = data['结果'].apply(lambda x: "正确" if x else "错误")
    print(data)
    fig = px.scatter(data, x=data.columns[0], y=data.columns[1], color='True',
                     symbol='结果', symbol_map={'正确': 'circle', '错误': 'x'},
                     # hover_data=data.columns[:-3],text=range(1, len(data) + 1),
                     labels={"True": y_name})

    x_buttons = [
        dict(
            label=feature,
            method="update",
            args=[{'x', [data[feature]]}]
        ) for feature in data.columns[:-3]
    ]

    y_buttons = [
        dict(
            label=feature,
            method="update",
            args=[{'y', [data[feature]]}]
        ) for feature in data.columns[:-3]
    ]
    print(x_buttons, y_buttons)

    fig.update_layout(
        title=title,
        xaxis_title=data.columns[0],
        yaxis_title=data.columns[1],
        updatemenus=[
            {
                'buttons': x_buttons,
                'direction': 'down',
                'xanchor': 'left',
                'yanchor': 'top',
                'x': 1.02,
                'y': 0.3,
            },
            {
                'buttons': y_buttons,
                'direction': 'down',
                'xanchor': 'left',
                'yanchor': 'top',
                'x': 1.02,
                'y': 0.2,
                # 'pad': {}
                'active': 1,
            },
        ],
    )
    fig.show(config=config)
```

then we get the graph looks like great,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I25Kw.png)
when I change the y-axis from SepalWidth to PetalLength, y-axis tilte change,but the hover data is not updated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izKlt.png)
What's even weirder is when I choose the same feature for the x and y axes, it's not a straight line [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sENAp.png)
Even when I chose the original x and y features, the resulting image was actually different from the original.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ip4x8.png)
This problem has troubled me for a long time and has not been solved. I hope someone can point out the problem. Thank you very much!

I didn't find a solution to the problem of using two sets of buttons to update the X-axis and Y-axis features on this website and the plotly forum. I only found one set of buttons, but that was too cumbersome. I wanted to get a solution for keeping two sets of buttons。